# AOSP dialer app crash on nexus 6p

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-dialer, nexus-6p

I have been building aosp for angler (nexus 6p) device. After flashing the images, everything works find except dialer app. I am on "8.0.0_r17" tag, anyone else has same issue or any pointer for workaround on this ?

```
--------- beginning of crash
10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.dialer, PID: 5988

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.content.FileProvider> has no zero argument constructor

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6290)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:173)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.content.FileProvider> has no zero argument constructor

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6274)

10-24 21:32:35.860  5988  5988 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 10 more

10-24 21:32:35.863   841   852 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.dialer/.app.DialtactsActivity

10-24 21:32:35.869   841   857 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.android.dialer u0
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it fixed by

-LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := custom
+LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := custom nosystem

and adding -dontoptimize to proguard.